# How to filter query for specific types of parent lookup?

Tags: soql, dynamic-soql

`for (SObject deletedObject : [SELECT Id, isDeleted, LastModifiedDate, parentId  FROM Attachment WHERE isDeleted = true AND LastModifiedDate >= :timestamp ALL ROWS]) {`

It appeared, that recently more than 50000 of Notes & Attachments were deleted. The trick is that all of them don't relate to my application - they wasn't linked to 'my' custom objects.
I'm wondering, is there any way, I can query Notes & Attachments for specific sObjects?

Comment: Isn't the FROM clause working for you here?  And what is the value in var "obj"?

Comment: Can you please dump your query without all the string concatenation? It is quite hard to read.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be done. Here is some [documentation](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm) on how it works. See the "Using the Type qualifier" section. This qualifier does not require polymorphism to be enabled in the org.

```
SELECT Id FROM Attachment WHERE Parent.Type = 'My_Object__c'
```

or

```
SELECT Id FROM Note WHERE Parent.Type = 'My_Object__c'
```

Comment: N.B. sadly (as of V41), this does not work: `select id from FeedComment where Parent.Type = 'Account'` - [see workaround](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/163731/query-feedcomments-for-specific-parent-type)