# Query FeedComments for specific parent Type

Tags: feeditem, chatter-feed, feedcomment

For FeedItems this works in SOQL:

```
[SELECT Id FROM FeedItem WHERE Parent.Type = :mySObjectType]
```

But for **FeedComment** it is not a valid query:

> Didn't understand relationship 'Parent' in field path

So I also tried to filter by key prefix:

```
String prefix = mySObjectType.getDescribe().getKeyPrefix() + '%';
[SELECT Id FROM FeedComment WHERE ParentId LIKE :prefix]
```

leads to:

> invalid operator on id field

Is there any other workaround, or even a clean way to select Comments posted on a parent of a certain type?

**EDIT:**
Also tried

```
[SELECT Id FROM FeedComment WHERE FeedItem.Parent.Type = :mySObjectType]
```

> Didn't understand relationship 'FeedItem' in field path

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sometimes fields declared as Reference do not really work as references. In such cases you need to use some ugly workarounds like this one:

```
SELECT Id, FeedItemId, ParentId, RelatedRecordId FROM FeedComment WHERE FeedItemId IN ( Select id from FeedItem WHERE Parent.Type = :mySObjectType )
```

Comment: Hmmm.. wasn't sure about this, cause it "querys" or lets say doublechecks way more Items than I need. But it is a workaround of cause! Let's wait for about 24 hours and if nothing else pops up I'll accept this as an answer!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the answer already presented, you **can't** use `LIKE` operator on an `id` field, as mentioned in the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl_where.htm)

> The LIKE operator is supported for **string** fields only.
>
> Id is not a string field, hence you can't use `LIKE` with Id fields.

As for the **FeedComment** object, I think the referential ids not being accessible via SOQL, is because this object is not supported to be used **directly**, as mentioned in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Salesforce_Chatter)

> The FeedComment is not directly accessible and **must be** accessed via an
>   Entity Feed

**Sample SOQL to access FeedComment**

```
SELECT Id, (SELECT Id, CommentBody, CreatedDate, CreatedById, 
                   CreatedBy.FirstName, CreatedBy.LastName
             FROM FeedComments )  
FROM [sObject]Feed
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I prefer the 'WHERE FeedItemId IN' approach for my case, since I only need Comments for a certain period, so I won't need to query all the FeedItems. The Documentation link is really helpful!